# Syntax Error in concat echo statement and html code

Tags: php, html, css, concatenation

Please help me to understand syntax of concat following

i want following code inside echo to understand concate

1-->  `<div class="alert   echo $_REQUEST['error_id'];?>"\>`

I try following code but getting syntax error that there is two echo..

2--> `echo "<div class=\"alert" . echo $_REQUEST['error_id']; . "\">";`

where mistake is that i cant get it... and `i want two answer` both using `single quote` and `double quote`

**EDIT**

Thank @Rizier123 now it working but css is not working as i have apply in **calss="alert"**

while using following code its working fine 
`<div class="alert   echo $_REQUEST['error_id'];?>"\>`

[image]

But after applying your code its not working..only text appear but background color is not comming nad boarder is also dissappear as below

[image]

**class name** is **alert** shows the status of login..

**EDIT**

Thanks again i just forget to put space after class name..

Comment: What is the name of your css class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write `echo` and `;` again!

So this should work:

```
//echo with double quotes
echo "<div class=\"alert" . $_REQUEST['error_id'] . "\">";        

//echo with single quotes
echo '<div class="alert' . $_REQUEST['error_id'] . '">';
```

Maybe you need to add a space if your class name includes spaces!(..."alert "...)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
echo '<div class=\"alert"' .  $_REQUEST['error_id'] . '">';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do either 2 ways

**1. PHP in HTML**

```
<div class="alert<?php echo $_REQUEST['error_id'];?>">
```

**2. HTML in PHP**

```
echo "<div class='alert". $_REQUEST['error_id'] ."'>";
```

Or you can also do like

```
echo "<div class=\"alert". $_REQUEST['error_id'] ."\">";
```